# python stoppable sched in separate thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduling, python-multithreading

I have a python schedule from `sched` module that I want to execute in a separate thread while being able to stop it at any moment. I looked the `threading module` but do not know which is the best approach to implement this.

example of the schedule:

```
>>> s.run()
one
two
three
end
```

example of the schedule in a thread:

```
>>> t = threading.Thread(target = s.run)
>>> t.start()
one
two
>>> print("ok")
ok
three
end
>>>
```

wanted result:

```
>>> u = stoppable_schedule(s.run)
>>> u.start()
>>>
one
two
>>> u.stop()
"schedule stopped"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing are threads that can be asynchronously stopped.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread), there are two main approaches.
One of them is to have the thread code check for some event (triggered by `u.stop()` in your example) every operation it makes.

The other solution is to force raise an error into some thread. This approach is simpler to implement, but may cause unexpected behavior and the more complex your thread code is, the more dangerous it gets.

```
import ctypes


ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, 0)
```

Where `tid` is the the thread to be terminated. You can get the thread id by running (in the thread):

```
print self._thread_id
```

More info about that in the [thread2](http://tomerfiliba.com/recipes/Thread2/) blog post by Tomer Filiba.

Comment: Thanks ! I had already read this other question without understanding the Exception part. What I did finally is to get the thread id with `t.ident` and to stop it with `ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(tid, ctypes.py_object(InterruptedError))`